# Php only available in CMD from certain folders

Tags: php, windows-7, cmd

For some reason I can only access `php` from certain `cmd` windows. Namely from doing `wndKey+R` then typing in `cmd`.

Inside this folder `php` will run as expected. However opening `cmd` anywhere else and it'll return

```
'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command,  
operable program or batch file.
```

It is added to my path correctly. Not sure why I would get this error... :/

Answer (score 1):

The most likely reason for this is that `php` is not located on your `path` environment variable.

Go to `Control Panel -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables -> Path -> Edit`, then make sure that the folder containing `php` is located in the `path` variable. If it is not, append it to the end of the `path` variable.